# openstreetmap hike bike map

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm new to Osmdroid Map, I have followed the steps in this site 
http://www.haakseth.com/?p=30
in order to create a tile, I use the Application "Mobile Atlas Creator" then choose the map source to be "openstreetmap hikebikemap" after that I have Create Atlas and a Zip Folder was generated that contain folders containing pictures
The Question is how can I now see these tiles in my Android Application ?
where should I copy my Zip Folder to ?
Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862534/download-maps-for-osmdroid/22868462#22868462

Comment: thank you I'll try the steps in the link and see

Comment: Itt doesn't work. It gives me an empty map!!