# Showing blank tiles osmdroid with Mobac offline tiles

Tags: android, dictionary, osmdroid

Refering to this question , [Download maps for osmdroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862534/download-maps-for-osmdroid)  and the accepted answer , on some device it shows blank grid ,though it shows marker ,i kept the zip file of Mobac created tiles in sdcard/osmdroid.

Comment: did you add WRITE_EXTERNAL permission in you manifest.xml ?

Comment: thanks MHP ,it works now ,but it worked on some devices without having that WRITE_EXTERNAL permission .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you add WRITE_EXTERNAL permission in you manifest.xml ?
osmdroid try to catch your loaded map on disk so need WRITE_EXTERNAL permission.
if on some device it work without this permision maybe osmdroid configuration is different or osmdroid folder exist on device.

Comment: @ MHP,   mwhat are the best possible  map tiles sources are avaliable other than MOBAC .And do you if we can change how osmdroid is finding tiles so than we can change the location of tiles .

Comment: because I use osmdroid in offline mode I don't know online source , I use default source as describe in osmdroid page(for online usage).