# Android - How to improve osmdroid offline map performance in term of reponse time

Tags: android, offline, osmdroid, timedelay

Now, I'm using my offline map osmdroid MapQuest (.zip file).
However, the delay action time is not very good.

Like: Map View Initialiation Time, 
Action Zoom Time
...

Are there some solution to improve its performance?
(like unzip .zip file or something else?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stand a lot better chance with something like the GEMF format that is explicitly designed for the job at hand rather than ZIP.  For big files it's way better.  It is what I recommend for my users.

Comment: I added my new .gemf file to sdcard/osmdroid but only the "grey grid" is shown.
Can you help me please?
m_mapView.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("MapQuest", ResourceProxy.string.mapquest_osm, 12, 18, 256, ".jpg", null));

Comment: I found the solution.
For someone who is interested:

OK IT WORKS WITH .PNG BUT NOT .JPG
There are some bug.

Comment: Some details about offline tiles - including GEMF bug and its workaround - can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862534/download-maps-for-osmdroid/22868462#22868462