# Missing tiles in osmdroid

Tags: java, android, tiles, osmdroid

I've got an app that uses osmdroid 4.3. The only mode I use is offline. Sometimes my app can not render few tiles. Seems like missing tiles. If I zoom in or zoom out, new tiles will be missed. I was following to osmdroid FAQ and I disabled hardware acceleration for map activity in manifest using

```
 android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

But nothing good happens. Tiles are still missing. What do?

Comment: have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=osmdroid+offline ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that:
1) you still have tiles in the osmdroid cache, from older online sessions
2) your offline file is not working at all. 
In this situation, you get tiles when they exist in the old cache, and nothing when they don't => missing tiles.

First of all, delete the osmdroid/tiles sub-directory.

Then closely follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862534/download-maps-for-osmdroid/22868462#22868462).

Comment: 1) I clear cache using clearTileCache() from time to time.  2) But it works. I've got few devices with the same offline map. First device works fine, but second has tile errors. Also, if I remove my tile folder and download file again, everything will be fine.