# osmdroid: How to load offline map from sdcard to MapView

Tags: android, osmdroid

I have generated a set of maps, zipped it under name `tiles.zip` and copied in `sdcard/osmdroid` folder. Here are `atlas` setting and folder content.

[image]

[image]

I used the example project [here](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/tree/master/OpenStreetMapViewer). 
It runs without error but my maps are not presented in `MapView`. Here is MainActivity and layout:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final GeoPoint BERLIN = new GeoPoint(52.516667, 13.383333);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        mapView.setUseDataConnection(true);

       mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
       IMapController mapViewController = mapView.getController();
       mapViewController.setZoom(15);
       mapViewController.setCenter(BERLIN);


    }
}
```

and

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}">

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As I tested, if I unzip the maps and add them as `assets`, maps are shown but in wrong order.

any idea what's wrong? 
thanks

**EDIT1**

Here my log:

[image]

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862534/download-maps-for-osmdroid/22868462#22868462

Comment: it seems that the problem is during reading directory (pls look at EDIT1

Comment: @Behy did you fixed the problem !? I have the same one right now !

Answer (score 1):

1) Do you have Berlin in your zoom level 15 tiles? If not, try to set zoom level to 1 or change map center to your region.

2) you do not need to create so many layers in MOBAC. Just select you area, zoom levels and add it at once. It might help. Other setting are same like in my project

Comment: it could be another problem but according to the app log (EDIT1), it seems that the problem is during reading directory.

Comment: @Behy Do you have those permissions in your android manifest file?
[osmdroid wiki](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library)

Comment: it seems that the problem was due to using a samsung phone. no problem when a Nexus is used