# Purpose of the `aBaseUrl` parameter in the class OnlineTileSourceBase?

Tags: android, osmdroid

I don't understand the purpose of the `aBaseUrl` parameter in the class `OnlineTileSourceBase`. My reason for inquiring is that I am trying to get offline tiles to display and thus far can't get it to work. I see the overlay I created, but no map data (just that grey grid) and I wonder if I need to set `aBaseUrl` to something appropriate.

The data is on the device is in *sdcard/osmdroid/tiles/Mapnik/*.
*Mapnik* contains folders *0, 1, ... 14*, which themselves contains folders which contain .jpg files.

Online, this code works (removing the call `setUseDataConnection(false)` and setting tile source to MAPNIK). Based on code by @nightfixed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842624/how-to-create-osmdroid-xytilesource-for-offline-tiles-in-version-4-1).

```
    public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        final private int MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL = 0;
        final private int MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL = 14;
        final private int TILE_SIZE = 256;
        final private String IMAGE_EXTENSION = ".jpg";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            CustomTileSource  tileSource = new CustomTileSource ("Default",   
                    MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL,     
                    MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL,   
                    TILE_SIZE,                      
                    IMAGE_EXTENSION,  
                    CustomTileSource.TILE_URL);  

            final MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
            mapView.setTileSource(tileSource);
            // mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
            mapView.setUseDataConnection(false); // keeps the mapView from loading online tiles using network connection.

        }

    }


   public class CustomTileSource extends OnlineTileSourceBase {

    public static String[] TILE_URL = {"my_url"};

    public CustomTileSource (String aName,
                             int aZoomMinLevel,
                             int aZoomMaxLevel,
                             int aTileSizePixels,
                             String aImageFilenameEnding,
                             String[] urlArray) {
        super(
                aName,
                aZoomMinLevel,
                aZoomMaxLevel,
                aTileSizePixels,
                aImageFilenameEnding,
                urlArray);

    }

    // returns the url for each tile, depending on zoom level
    // this is where I changed the return statement to take the first url from the string array of urls
    @Override
    public String getTileURLString(MapTile aTile) {
        return TILE_URL[0] + aTile.getX() + "+" + aTile.getY() + "+" + aTile.getZoomLevel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to follow closely this post: [Download maps for osmdroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862534/download-maps-for-osmdroid/22868462#22868462)

No need for CustomTileSource, just use mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);

If your tiles are in "Mapnik" dir (sdcard/osmdroid/tiles/Mapnik) then TileSource aName should be set to "Mapnik", not to "Default".

When offline, aBaseUrl doesn't matter.

Comment: In the post you link to, the url *http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/* is used and it works for me (when in online mode). If I put that url in a browser, I get *Sorry - we haven't been able to serve the content you asked for*. Why is this?

Comment: because that's just the base url. osmdroid adds various parameters to get 1 specific tile at each request.

Comment: OIC, so yes, if I do *http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/0/0/0.png* that I see the tile

Comment: great link, i just added most of the content to the osmdroid wiki.

Answer (score 1):

aBaseUrl is basically the primary url to the online map server. For example

http://tiles.mymapserver.com/mapdata  (note, complete fictitious)

After the `aBaseUrl`, osmdroid calculates with tiles to load via various algorithms and then appends something like `/Z/X/Y.jpg` to the end of the `aBaseUrl` string when downloading.